# SQL запрос с исключением

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli

Хочу чтобы запрос не выводил пользователя с **id** равным 1

```
$user_id = 1;
mysqli_query($db, "SELECT * FROM tb_users WHERE name LIKE '%$user%' 
OR username LIKE '%$user%' AND user_id !=".$user_id);
```

Данный код всеравно выводит этого пользователя. Где моя ошибка?

Comment: если вы используете оба предиката - `OR` и `AND` то условия к которым относится `OR` надо обернуть скобками: `WHERE (name LIKE '%$user%' 
OR username LIKE '%$user%') AND user_id !=".$user_id`

Answer (score 4):

Необходимо правильноо сгруппировать условия.

```
SELECT * 
FROM tb_users 
WHERE 
(name LIKE '%$user%' OR username LIKE '%$user%') AND user_id != $user_id
```